# How to use with-max to set a turtles-own variable in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a breed worker, who has turtles-own variables pay and friend_pay, and I'd like to set a worker's friend_pay to be the highest pay from a near-by turtle. I tried the following, but it's not quite right. Can anyone please help?

```
ask workers [set friend_pay [pay] of [one-of workers in-radius 5 with-max [pay]] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `max-one-of` primitive is your friend. It also doesn't complain if there are two equally paid friends. I think this does what you want.

```
breed [workers worker]
workers-own [pay friend-pay]

to setup
  create-workers 50
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set pay random 100
  ]
  ask workers [ set friend-pay [pay] of max-one-of workers in-radius 5 [pay] ]
end
```